# Alert box not showing properly

Tags: html, css

I have a website where users can submit posts, when they do it they recieve alert message (success or warning). Im displaying alert messages on top of the page and im using `position: absolute` so that it can't move things around when it pops up. And everything is great and its all working but my SIGN UP/OUT button is showing inside my alert box and not behind it like my whole navigation.

[Here is it how Sign Up button is showing in front of alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARnfx.png)

And I want the Sign Up/Out button to show behind the alert message, like other navigation elements.

**Sign up button css:**

```
.navbar-brand, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #778489;
    text-shadow: 0 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    position: relative;
}

li.sign-up {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**Alertbox CSS**

```
.alertMsg {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 12px;
    position: absolute;
}
    .alertMsg i {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

**Sign up HTML:**

```
<li class="sign-up"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#signOut"><span class="white">Link Text</span></a></li>
```

I will be really thankful for any help, I've been dealing with this problem for some time. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using z-index which specifies the stack order of HTML elements. If one z-index is higher than another z-index then it will stack on top of it like a layer. Let me know if this works out. Also feel free to post up a a working demo of your code for better troubleshooting.

```
.navbar-brand, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a,
li.sign-up{
  z-index:3000; /* Number doesn't matter as long as it's higher than the .alertMsg z-index */
}

.alertMsg,
.alertMsg i{
  z-index:9999; /* Will be above anything below 9999 */
}
```

Comment: Man thanks a lot! This worked and helped a lot, I learned something new about z-index. Thanks again, will mark this as asnwer.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped and that you learned something new!